# Is it always true that operator norm assume supremum in definition?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that $X, Y$ are  normed vector spaces. 
Let $T: X \longrightarrow Y$ be linear operator.
We define $\Vert T \Vert := \sup\{\Vert Tx \Vert : x \in X, \ \Vert x \Vert = 1\}$.

Is it always true for $\Vert T \Vert$ to assume (reach) supremum?

If not are there any examples?

Comment: If $Y$ is the base field (either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), then this happens (for every functional $T$) if and only if $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: I think a better wording would be "always attain (reach) its supremum".  The title asks about if we "assume supremum in definition", which suggests possible use of different vector norms to define an operator norm.

Answer (score 6):

No, the norm does not necessarily assume its supremum.

For example: take $T:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ to be given by
$$
T[(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty] = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}x_n\right)_{n=1}^\infty
$$
We have $\|T\| = 1$, but there is no non-zero $x \in \ell^2$ with $\|Tx\| = \|x\|$.

Comment: This has deeper consequences. Note that if bounded+closed=compact, this could not happen.

Comment: In a finite dimensional setting the supremum is always attained.

Comment: Are those $i$'s supposed to be $n$'s?

Comment: @JonasDahlbæk well spotted

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Consider the operator from $ c_{00} $, the finitely supported sequences equipped with supreme norm, into the reals that maps $(a_n) $ to $\sum_n a_n 2^{-n}$. You may verify yourself that the operator norm is 1 and is not attained