# Show that the operator $T[(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty] = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}x_n\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ has norm $1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**Notation:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces.
Assume that $T:X\to Y$ is a linear operator with norm 
$$\|T\|:=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|.$$
Recall that 
$$\ell^2=\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty: \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\|^2<\infty \}.$$

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296619/is-it-always-true-that-operator-norm-assume-supremum-in-definition), OP asked the following question:

> **Question:** Is it always true that operator norm attain supremum?

Omnomnomnom gives the following answer:

> For example: take $T:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ to be given by
>   $$
> T[(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty] = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}x_n\right)_{n=1}^\infty
> $$
>   We have $\|T\| = 1$, but there is no non-zero $x \in \ell^2$ with $\|Tx\| = \|x\|$.

I have trouble showing $\|T\|=1.$

I can show that $\|Tx\|\neq \|x\|$ for all $x\in\ell^2.$
Indeed, for any $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in \ell^2,$ we have 
$$\|T(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\| = \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{n-1}{n}\bigg)^2 \|x_n\|^2} < \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\|^2} =\|(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\|.$$

By similar reasoning, I can also show that $\|T\|\leq 1.$
However, I fail to show that $\|T\| =1.$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget the square root: $$||(x_n)_{n = 1}^\infty|| = \left( \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |x_n|^2 \right)^{1/2}.$$

Comment: @TrevorGunn: Thanks for pointing out. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\delta_m = (\delta_m(n))_{n = 1}^\infty$ be the sequence defined by $\delta_m(n) = 1$ if $m = n$ and $\delta_m(n) = 0$ otherwise. So $\delta_m$ is the sequence $0,0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots$ with the $1$ in the $m$-th position. We then have

$$ T\delta_m = 0,0,\dots,0,\frac{m-1}{m},0,\dots$$

So as you can see, $||\delta_m|| = 1$ and $||T\delta_m|| = (m - 1)/m$.

You've already seen that $||T|| \le 1$. This shows that

$$ ||T|| \ge \frac{m-1}{m}, \quad \forall m \ge 1,$$

and it follows that $||T|| = 1$.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much.